# Use vbscript to set local user's terminal services startup environment

Tags: windows-server-2003, vbscript

If I was in AD, the parameters would look like:
objUser.ConnectClientDrivesAtLogon = Enabled
objUser.ConnectClientPrintersAtLogon = Enabled
objUser.DefaultToMainPrinter = Enabled
objUser.TerminalServicesInitialProgram = "something"
objUser.TerminalServicesWorkDirectory = "c:\something"

But these don't work when not in AD. How do I programmatically set these values for local, non-AD users?

I'm not tied to vbscript, if you know of another way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Those properties are not defined for accounts on a local computer.

Are the values going to be the same for every user?  You could just configure the per-computer settings on your terminal server.

Comment: They will not be the same for every user. The values I'm trying to set are the checkboxes and fields on the Environment tab of a local Windows user.